# Graph function from multiple coefficient estimates with ggplot in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to graph the implied functions from my regression estimates on the same figure in ggplot. In the example below i create a simple linear function where c and b are coefficient estimates stored from a earlier regression. I am trying to then plot the functions over the range [0,50] by groups (preferably also using the option: colour = groups).

```
library(ggplot2)

groups = c("a", "b", "c")
c = c(5, 4, 3)
b = c(-0.01, -0.002, -0.001)
x = c(0, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(cbind(c, b, x))

grad_fun <- function(x) {
  c + b*x
}

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, group = groups)) +
  stat_function(fun = grad_fun) + 
  xlim(0, 50)
```

My figure comes out like this, but i cannot seem to find out why. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem are welcome.
[Image: Outcome of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxp4V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Instead of using a custom function, `geom_abline` is your friend here.
- Note that `group = group` doesn't do anything in this case -- you need to specify how the group will be displayed, so it should be `color = group`.
- Finally, be careful about using `cbind` where it's not necessary -- it was turning your numeric parameters into factors, which then couldn't be plotted.

The code below should do what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

groups = c("a", "b", "c")
c = c(5, 4, 3)
b = c(-0.01, -0.002, -0.001)
df <- data.frame(c, b, groups)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = b, intercept = c, color = groups)) +
  xlim(0,50) + ylim(0,5)
```

`geom_abline` works only for affine functions of the form y = m*x + b. If instead, you want to use any function, you need to use `stat_function` and add them in a loop like below. You could also add colors to the data

```
library(ggplot2)

groups = c("a", "b", "c")
a = c(-1, 3, 2)
c = c(5, 4, 3)
b = c(-0.01, -0.002, -0.001)
colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(a), "Dark2")
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, groups, x = 0, colors)

fun <- function(x, a, b, c){
  function(x) a*x^2 + b*x + c 
}

funs <- mapply(fun, a = df$a, b = df$b, c = df$c)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x)) +
  xlim(-50,50) 

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  p <- p +
    stat_function(fun = funs[[i]], color = colors[i])
}

print(p)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! What about if i want to include a polinomial term, i.e. c + bx + bx^2 or a logarithmic functional form, i.e. ln(y) = c + b*ln(x)? Can geom_abline handle that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex, this is exactly what i was looking for!